# Upgrading to PHP 5.6 using Yum (REMI repo)

Tags: centos, httpd, php5

I would like to ask how to upgrade to PHP 5.6 on my CentOS machine using Yum + REMI repo.

For example, I already use the REMI repo for everything.

Now, after I change this line in `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`:

```
[remi-php56]
enabled=0
```

to

```
enabled=1
```

I can now see the PHP 5.6.2 package on the repo. If I simpy update as such `yum update php`, will that update the entire PHP package (ie php_mysql, pdo, etc) ?

And what about mod_php in httpd? (Apache)?

Or are there other steps I need to take?

Comment: Have you at least tried it to see what it would do?

Comment: @MichaelHampton :) no, this is a production server, and is currently live!

Comment: You don't have to say "yes" at the prompt!

Comment: Don't you have a development server to test it on?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean: It fails after Dependency Resolution, and it shows below ' You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest'

Comment: @ceejayoz Nope. Just the live VPS. I did most of my 'learning' before going live, and when I did have two servers, I forgot to upgrade PHP

Answer (score 3):

You made need to install php56 explicitly, e.g.:

```
yum install php56 php56-php-cli  php56-php-common php56-php-pear php56-php-pecl-jsonc php56-php-pecl-zip php56-php-process php56-php-xml php56-runtime
```

and then remove the old php, e.g.

```
yum remove php55 php55-php-cli  php55-php-common php55-php-pear php55-php-pecl-jsonc php55-php-pecl-zip php55-php-process php55-php-xml php55-runtime
```

You can run `yum list installed |grep php` to see which PHP packages are already installed.

Comment: I also add some additinal packages as `yum install php56-php-fpm php56-php-pdo` as well

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

so to upgrade, do the following:

make sure that in the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`, that you enable the remi-php56 repo

```
[remi-php56]
enabled=1
```

And you can then do 'yum update php`.

If you get problems such as inconsistency between Modules API and PHP API, the installation still works. But you may end up having to update PECL + PERL.

What I did was uninstall all PHP packages which you can find by looking up `rpm -qa | grep php` and then uninstalling `yum remove php php-cli php-common php-mysql php-pear php-pecl php-pdo php-xml`

and of course reinstalling `yum install php php-cli php-common php-mysql php-pear php-pecl php-pdo php-xml` which will give you the new version.

And, don't forget to restart httpd `service httpd restart`